# ¿Como detectar cambios de la base de datos en mi DataGridView C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo un `DataGridView` que se llena desde una consulta de base de datos, lo que deseo hacer es como detectar cambios en la base de datos y se actualize en tiempo real en mi `DataGridView` y me mande un MessageBox cada vez que haya cambios en la base de datos.

He escuchado de SqlDependency pero no se como implementarlo.

Mi clase Conexión

```
public class Conexion
    {
        public SqlConnection getConexion()
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
            return cn;
        }
    }
```

Mi clase Negocios

```
public class Negocios
    {
        Conexion objCon = new Conexion();

        public DataTable listarPersonas()
        {
            var cn = objCon.getConexion();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Persona", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            cn.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Mi Form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgListado.DataSource = objNegocios.listarPersonas();
            dgListado.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si pudieras contarnos un poco más de lo que sucede en tu aplicación...pienso que tienes un formulario y un DGV en el mismo form y que al presionar un botón para enviar los datos, quieres que el DGV se actualice automáticamente. ¿Estoy en lo correcto? ¿O de que manera obtiene nuevos datos tu base de datos?

Comment: Estas en lo correcto. Al iniciar el form el DataGridView ya esta con datos de la base de datos, lo que quiero es que detecte cuando por ejemplo haya una inserción en sql server y en el datagridview se actualize solo sin tener que presionar un boton en tiempo real.

Comment: Ese form muestra datos en un DataGridView solamente eso.Yo deseo que se actualize en tiempo real